# Debug django heroku foreman using pycharm

Tags: django, heroku, pycharm, foreman

I have recently moved over to Heroku for deploying Django applications. It works well however I use Pycharm to debug and have recently run into a problem as Pycharm won't debug using the .env file environment variables. How do I debug a Django application using foreman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately loading environment variables from .env files is not supported yet. You can vote for the issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5543 to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can read local default environment variables from .env file and set them in your environment. This has been well documented here - http://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/easier-12-factor-django/

Answer (score 0):

I work around this with a code block that I manually call at the top of files when debugging. It's a pretty lame but worky solution:

```
import os


def load_environment():
    env = {}
    with open('.env', 'r') as env_file:
        env_vars = env_file.readlines()
        for v in env_vars:
            v = v.strip().replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
            if v and v[0] != '#':
                v = v.split('=')
                env[v[0]] = v[1]

    os.environ.update(env)
```

then from whatever app or script I'm debugging, call it e.g.:

```
from debug.environment_loader import load_environment
load_environment()
```

before accessing any environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

As documented at the [support page](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5543) linked in [Dmitry’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11285889/134610), there’s now a 3rd-party PyCharm plugin called [EnvFile](https://github.com/Ashald/EnvFile) that will import your `.env`’s contents before execution.